# how can i count the number of duplicate objects in an object

Tags: javascript, html, object, count

I have an object "b" which has many objects inside it, and I want to see how many of a particular object I have inside this.

Object "b" has inside it: `object k, object k, array cat`.

What i want to do is have something that returns the number of times object "b" contains object "k". This should be 2 because there are 2 instances of this object. I can't seem to get the length.

I have tried `keys(b).length` but this returned the total of all object including not object k.

Example:
`b["k","k","property","cat"]`

How can I get total of "k" from the above example?

Comment: Can you give an exemple of the structure of the object b.

Comment: ive updated the question

Comment: in your example above, "k" is a String not an Object

Answer (score 0):

Of course keys(b).length return the length of an array. What you can do is loop the keys(b) and check if the apperance of K and count the apperance.

Comment: can you please give example

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the items in your array and count only those elements which match what you are looking for.

Lets say that your Array `b` looks like this:

```
var b = ['k', 'k', 'property', 'cat'];
```

Your function to return just the number of strings "k" would be like this:

```
function elementCount(arr, element) {
  var count = 0;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === element) {
      count++
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

You can now get the number of "k" elements by running:

```
kCount = elementCount(b, 'k');
```

Another way of defining this function is to use `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```
function elementCount(arr, element) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, next) {
    if (next === 'k') {
      return prev + 1;
    } else {
      return prev;
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: if i have an array "b" -  this array  b ["k","k","property","cat"], how can i loop and find the number of "k" ?